# I want to find the three-dimensional coordinates of the light hitting the surface of an object

Tags: rendering, lighting, coordinates

I simulated the effect of a laser with a light, causing it to shine on an object, as shown in the figure. Now I want to find the pixel coordinates of the light bar after rendering is completed. Is there any good method?
[image][image]

I have tried using a Python program to create multiple rays that intersect with the surface of an object, but the results achieved by this method have some errors compared to the actual results.

Comment: Could you show us / describe your general strategy? Could you extract the pixels from a rendered image, and let the renderer do the work for you?